# Send data using redirect action using Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I need to use something like this one :

```
return redirect()->action([HomeController::class, 'index'])->with('data'=>$data);
```

but I don't know how ?

Comment: I think [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Action method accepts two parameters which are array both. Second array is associative array of key as parameter name and value of parameter value.
In your case it would be

```
return redirect()->action(
    [HomeController::class, 'index'], 
    ['data' => $data]
);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions).

Comment: You are most welcome. Feel free to accept answer (and vote up) if does solve your issue. Happy coding.